# Why creating an emptyRDD using parallelize method is not recommended?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, rdd

I am learning apache- spark and trying to create an empty RDD.
I got the following ways to create an empty RDD:

```
1. JavaRDD<String> emptyRDD = sc.emptyRDD();
2. List<String> emptyList = new ArrayList<String>();
   JavaRDD<String> emptyParallelRDD = sc.parallelize(emptyList, 1);
```

And the code works perfectly fine in both cases, no error and no exception.

But as of the documentation of parallelize method:

> avoid using parallelize(Seq()) to create an empty RDD. Consider emptyRDD for an RDD with no partitions

for which i did not find any reason.
Any help, why shouldn't we use parallelize for creating emptyRDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `EmptyRDD` has zero partitions

```
sc.emptyRDD[Int].getNumPartitions
// Int = 0
```

Whereas the following will have a default number of partitions with no data :

```
sc.parallelize(Seq[Int]()).getNumPartitions
// Int = 2
```

My guess would be, in the first case, any job involving the empty RDD should be quicker because no partitions will result in no job getting executed at all.

For instance, `saveAsTextFile` will not generate a part file in the first case but would generate two empty part files in the second one.

```
scala> sc.emptyRDD[Int].saveAsTextFile("emptyRDDTest")

scala> sc.parallelize(Seq[Int]()).saveAsTextFile("emptySeqTest")

$ hdfs dfs -ls empty*
Found 1 items
hadoop          0 2017-12-07 02:38 emptyRDDTest/_SUCCESS
Found 3 items
hadoop          0 2017-12-07 02:39 emptySeqTest/_SUCCESS
hadoop          0 2017-12-07 02:39 emptySeqTest/part-00000
hadoop          0 2017-12-07 02:39 emptySeqTest/part-00001
```